# Is there some additional Information about the killer couple in The Raid 2?

Tags: character, the-raid-2

In *The Raid 2* there is a Killer couple. He uses a baseball and a bat, she wears sunglasses, has a destroyed eye, does not speak and uses hammers. Is there some more information about the characters? Is there an extended Version where their background is explained or did I miss something during the movie?

Are the characters also in other movies or movies planned for them or only invented for *The Raid 2*? Or maybe there is a book/comic or interview information about them which explain why she lost her eye, why they are working as killers and are in some kind of relationship? (At Wikipedia they say they are brother and sister, but I cannot remember a scene in the movie where this is stated.) Any information about this would be nice.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, because noone did answer I did some more research on my own. I found [this very interesting article](http://www.fangoria.com/new/the-raid-2-hammer-girl-gareth-evans-julie-estelle/) where the writer of Raid 2 describes the background story of the characters and answers nearly all my questions:

The Director/Writer of The Raid 2 had the idea for them a long time ago and wanted to use them in another movie, but then decided to use them in The Raid 2. There background story is, they killed their abusive father as children in teamwork and were then quickly recruited by the minion of The Raid 2 who took care for their training as assassins.

So, if someone else is interested in this, he should read this article.